# Postfix change add-on priority

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, spam-filter, policyd

I have just started to fight with Spam mails because of my new project. I will explain structure of that system.

We have Postfix as MTA on relay server and fresh Spamassasian and Policyd(v2 Cluebringer) add-ons for it. These are working well and they generate good outputs in log files.

My Question in this schema,how I can learn which add-on is working first?

Why I want to learn this:

- If Policyd is reject mails because being not real mail address Spamassasian will not work and system will not work to scan all mails
- If I install Clamav, it will not use so much resources

Best Regards.

postconf -M

```
smtp       inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin
pickup     unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
spamassassin unix -      n       n       -       -       pipe user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
policy-spf unix  -       n       n       -       -       spawn user=nobody argv=/usr/sbin/postfix-policyd-spf-perl
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
```

postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localdomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = UNKNOWN
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128, ~~~RELAY SERVER IP~~~
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031, permit_mynetworks
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031, permit_mynetworks
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Comment: Post the output of command `postconf -n` and/or `postconf -M`

Comment: @masegaloeh I add postconf outputs ass you want

Comment: Thanks man your help all of these worked well. @masegaloeh and I understand how postfix works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config above you have Spamassassin and Policyd(v2 Cluebringer).

Email was fed to Policyd, because of this configuration

```
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
```

That means postfix will send email to Policyd who listen at port 10031. You can find out about `check_policy_service` parameter in this page: [Postfix SMTP Access Policy Delegation](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html)

On the other hand you feed email to SpamAssassin using this line of configuration

```
smtp     inet  n     -     -     -     -     smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin
```

You can find out about this setup on [Postfix After-Queue Content Filter](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html).

---

**So, what's the order of the add-on?**

Here the simplified diagram of postfix filter

```
email ---> smtpd ---> check_policy_service ---> qmgr ---> SpamAssasin
```

Policyd (via `check_policy_service`) can't access the header and body of the email, so you can put the lightweight checks first. After postfix queued the email, postfix will pass it to heavy checks spamassassin.